# Limiting GitHub Actions execution to specific branches

Tags: github, github-actions

I have set some GH repo-level secrets.

I want to protect those secrets from being incorporated into a rogue workflow, i.e. I want to avoid the following scenario from being materialised:

1. User creates a branch:

   ```sh
   git checkout my-malicious-branch
   ```
2. and adds a `workflow.yaml` using a sensitive value (by say dumping it on the logs, the action per se doesn't matter for the moment):

   ```sh
   echo "${{ env.MY_SUPER_SECRET }}"
   ```
3. They push to remote and the workflow runs:

   ```sh
   git add workflow.yaml
   git -m "Evil Laughter" commit workflow.yaml 
   git push -u origin my-malicious-branch
   ```

I know that one can protect an *existing* [workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) just checking whether there is a repo-level configuration similar to: "Run workflows only from those branches".

Important Note: I am trying to cover the scenario where the potentially malicious user is already a collaborator (that's why the GHActions workflow execution restriction requirement)

Comment: If a secret (or a value that happens to be the value of a secret) gets logged, it's replaced with asterisks for exactly this reason.

Comment: correct; however that does not cover the scenario where the user does a `curl -H "Authorization: OAuth ${{ env.MY_SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN }}" http://www.superbank.com/getAllTheUsersMoneyToMyAccount`

Comment: No, it doesn't. But for the user to push directly to your repo they'd already be a collaborator anyway, secrets aren't exposed to PR builds from forks ([_"we run all pull request workflows raised from repository forks with a read-only token and no access to secrets"_](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/)).

Comment: You are right this wasn't clear in my original question so I followed up with an edit; I am talking about collaborators (i.e. can create / push to braches) and this is why I am asking whether I can restrict workflow execution on a branch (say `master`)

Comment: Then you probably want https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers

Comment: Ι think this is indeed the way to go about this; so if you post it i will mark your answer as accepted